# IntelliJ: Module not found JavaFX

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I know this is a often-asked question but none of the answers I found on the internet helped me. My setup is: maven project with JavaFX as dependency defined in the pom.xml.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382694/maven-module-not-found-javafx-fxml). But to no avail..
Here is my [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/cvndpYKG)

The relevant `pom.xml` entry:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
      ...
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the specific problem you encounter; a [mre] may make your intent more clear.

Comment: You have stuff in your pastebin which is not in your question (please don't do that, make the question standalone).  The stuff in pastebin is probably relevant to your issue (e.g. it uses an assembly plugin and a jar plugin with dependencies and whatever the google addjars thing is doing).  None of those additional tasks are standard for a JavaFX project, I don't recommend them.  Follow the instructions at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) or the [steps in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498158/java-lang-module-findexception-module-test-not-foundintellidea).

Comment: @jewelsea, of course there is stuff in pastebin that is not relevant, as I literally posted the whole of my pom.xml for clarification.. no, the stuff is not relevant to my question as IntelliJ reports JavaFX as missing and not maven.. this is an error on IntelliJs side not on the build systems, thanks for your links but none helped

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you haven't included the plugin. Add this piece of code to your pom.xml file.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Reference to JavaFX documentation: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven

Comment: It is already included: I got it under plugins starting in line 94

Comment: @Fingolfin please share your full build.gradle.

Comment: It is already linked under `Here is my pom.xml` but.. here we go again: [LINK](https://pastebin.com/cvndpYKG)  this is btw not an answer, as one can see its already included in my [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/cvndpYKG)